# What is the meaning of a number in brackets after a struct declaration?

Tags: c

I recently encountered text of the form

```
struct {
    double a, b, c;
}[123];
```

What exactly does this do? Is this even proper C?

Comment: I doubt this compiles.

Comment: Is the snippet perhaps missing something between `}` and `[`?

Comment: It's very possible it does not compile as C. I am actually reading through a custom data file but its syntax is designed to be as similar as possible to C's, motivating my post in the manner in which it is written. I apologize if this was troublesome/annoying to those looking at the question.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Noted and corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly does this do? Is this even proper C?

This is an ill formed code. Compiler will raise syntax error. There should be an identifier before `[123]`.

```
struct {
    double a, b, c;
} a[123];
```

This will declare `a` as an array of 123 `struct { double a, b, c; }`.

Comment: Should also explain what it would do if valid.

Comment: I think in your edit you removed the very identifier that was missing.